# Rescaling Y axis in a plot

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, axis-labels

I am trying to adjust the y axis and change it to be from `[0 2.5]` and to show that it has to be multiplied by a factor of 1000.

Obviously setting the limit with `ylim=([0 25])` doesn't work and I can't find a way to do it.

[image]

Using to plot:

```
AveTime = 1.0e+03 * [0.0020, 0.0291, 0.1279, 0.3061, 2.0599];
STDtime = [0.0519, 0.0117, 0.0166, 0.0071, 0.0165];
errorbar([10,25,50,75,100], AveTime, STDtime);
```

Comment: Your best bet is to divide your Y values by 1000, plot them, then indicate that in the axis label (you can use [`ylabel`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ylabel.html)). Note1: In some case (with unit like time), you could simply use `ms` instead of `s` (or the relevant sub-unit) when you label the units. Note2: didn't you mean a range [0 2.5] (instead of 25 as the high limit)?

Comment: @Hoki that is actually a good idea. Yes I missed the `.` as I copied and pasted. Many thanks!

Comment: You can change that to [0 2.5] but how do you intend to show that "*the ticks  has to be multiplied by a factor of 1000." Scientific notation?

Comment: @SardarUsama in Y axis I can label it `time in Kseconds`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is what you need, it should work for Matlab versions >= 2014b:

```
ax = gca;
ax.YAxis.Exponent = 3;
```

Here's a code example:

```
clear;
close all;
clc;

x=1:10:1000;
y=3*x;
plot(x,y);
ax = gca;
ax.YAxis.Exponent = 3;
```

And the plot:

[image]

Comment: Much neater than having to modify the data or the tick labels. You should precise that it will only works for HG2, so for Matlab versions >= 2014b.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a workaround:
Get the `YTick`, divide them by `1000` and set them as `YTickLabel`.

```
set(gca,'YTickLabel',get(gca,'YTick')/1000);
```

In MATLAB R2014b or later, you can also use:

```
ax=gca;
ax.YTickLabel= ax.YTick/1000;
```

---

On the downside, as [Hoki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3460361/hoki) mentioned in the comments,

> This is good but only for the final rendering of the figure (if you just want to look/print it). Once you override the `YTickLabel`, their mode change from `auto` to `manual` and any zoom/pan or modification of the axis limit will keep the existing tick labels which may be obsolete after the figure modification.

Comment: This is better than the suggestion in the comment. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: This is good but only for the *final* rendering of the figure (if you just want to look/print it). Once you override the `YTickLabel`, their mode change from `auto` to `manual` and any zoom/pan or modification of the axis limit will keep the existing tick labels which may be obsolete after the figure modification.

Comment: @Hoki agreed with that :/ What do you suggest? I initially suggested the scientific notation though

Comment: @SardarUsama. I can't suggest much more. Both our tricks are just workarounds (because the functionality doesn't even exist in older Matlab version) so they have downside too, some elements have to be managed by the user. The answer by David is actually what I would use because it is built-in.

Comment: @Hoki I agree. But on the downside, it is undocumented

Comment: @SardarUsama. I thought so, but actually it is documented: [NumericRuler Properties](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/numericruler-properties.html)

Comment: @Hoki Thanks for the insight